# Grafana - Promql cumulative graph

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

this seems like a pretty easy thing to do. Yet I cannot wrap my head around it.

I make some calculations depending on the average CPU Utilization for the last 15s and get a value based of that calculation. No I want a graph in Grafana which shows the cumulative result. E.g.

| Time passed | Current result | Cumulative result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 15s | 5 | 5 |
| 30s | 7 | 12 |
| 45s | 6 | 18 |

At the moment my query looks something like:

```
sum (((1 - (avg by (cpu, instance) (rate(node_cpu_seconds_total{mode="idle"}[15s])))) * 2 + 4
```

This results in a graph plotting the current results. But I want a query plotting the cumulative results. When I try to wrap the whole query with a *sum_over_time*, I get the following exception: "expected type matrix in call to function "sum_over_time", got vector"

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

PromQL in Prometheus doesn't support functions for cumulative calculations. If you need cumulative calculations, then try [VictoriaMetrics](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/) instead - its query language - [MetricsQL](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html) - provides [running_sum()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#running_sum) function.

P.s.: I'm the author of VictoriaMetrics.